# How to remove newline from .open() list

Tags: python, scripting

So I'm just writing a bit of code to assist me with something. I have a wordlist of 4 digit numbers that I intend to attach to, say, 2 letters. Like this:
`aXXXXa`

However, because it is a list of numbers there is a newline that gets added, which affects the output of the file.

Here is the code:

```
file = open("numbers.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    a = "b"
    print(a + line + a)
```

The resulting output is:

```
b9989
b
b9990
b
b9991
b
```

which is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Strip the newline when you concatenate the strings

```py
print(a + line.strip('\n') + a)
```

Answer (score 0):

strip() only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string. You want to use replace()

```
file = open("numbers.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    a = "b"
    print("a" + line.replace("\n","") + "a")
```